# Putting in a Google Search One Letter At a Time Using Visual Basic

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-9

I would like to use VBA to run a Google search.  It is important for me to be able to put in the search word one letter at a time into the Google search bar.  This is my current code:

`myie.document.all("q").Value = "cheese"`

This will load the search term "cheese" into the search bar in one complete interval.  I would like the search to be done in a more natural human manner; with "c" being typed into the search bar then "h" and then "e", etc...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the main purpose? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, a little more clarification on the end goal here would be helpful in figuring out the best solution.

Comment: @Lloyd Banks: I have removed the `VB.Net` tag as you mentioned that you want to do it in VBA. If you meant VB.Net then let us know and we will make the necessary edits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "Google.com"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim strtext As String
    Dim i As Long

    strtext = "cheese"

    For i = 1 To Len(strtext)
        WebBrowser1.Document.all("q").Value = WebBrowser1.Document.all("q").Value & Mid(strtext, i, 1)
        Wait 1
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

If you are bothered with the all results showing up when you type then you can use this as well

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    '~~> Choose one of the below
    IE.Navigate ("http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=" & "Cheese") '<~~ US
    IE.Navigate ("http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=" & "Cheese") '<~~ UK
    IE.Navigate ("http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=" & "Cheese") '<~~ INDIA
End Sub
```

Comment: Code goes to Google and the following is run:     myie.document.all("q").Value = "cheese"
    myie.document.all("btnG").Click  The first part types "cheese" into the google search bar and the second part of the code clicks the "search" button.  "Cheese" is currently inserted into the search bar as a whole word all at once.  I would like each letter of "Cheese" to be inserted into the search bar one at a time